# What is this film about ninjas and video games?

Tags: story-identification, movie

I need help identifying a tv sci-fi action movie from 2000-2006, maybe filmed in France, but the language is probably English. It might have ninja aspects.

I remember a scene where this woman (might be Japanese) gives birth in the forest; it was raining I think. Within seconds the baby rapidly grew into an adult (maybe it was also cocooned) and killed his mother (the host). There's another scene where this guy buys this game from a video-game store, a game that maybe hasn't come out yet, and the video game somehow transmits a signal to a neck implant.

That's all I recall. Oh, and the ending is that a kid is playing the video game (in the apartment) and the guy fights the monster (the baby from before, I think) on the roof and makes him do some martial arts moves and cuts off the monster's head I think. It was a nice ending.

P.S.- i think there is another girl thats gonna be a "host" and the hero protects her....

Comment: That is a lot of thinking.

Comment: I know the movie you are talking about I just cannot find the name. It's centered around the video game for some reason. There is also an executive of the video game company who comes to help protect the girl that is pregnant. He's a ninja. The kid at the end is controlling a human through the video game against the evil guy. This is probably the worst added information I've ever put on a post.

Comment: My 11-year-old self desperately wants to see this.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I think that you are remembering *Samourais*, a French movie.

> Directed by Giordano Gederlini and produced by the same folks who packaged Francois Ozon's 8 Women, *Samourais* gives martial arts movies a rarely seen French twist. Beginning in feudal Japan, a pregnant woman manages to escape persecution long enough to have her baby, Kodeni (Santi Sudaros), a human-looking demon whose bald head reveals the shape of a spider peaking up from beneath the skin. Fast forward to present day Japan, where the death of a video-game engineer is traced back to Kodeni's goons. Though Tokyo policeman Fujiwara (Yasuaki Kurata) manages to foil and temporarily kill Kodeni, he is visited by the spirit of an ancient warrior, who warns him that Fujiwara's daughter, Akemi (Mai Anh Le), will give birth to the reincarnation of Kodeni. In order to prevent Kodeni's return, Fujiwara must travel to France, where his daughter has been studying for two years, and kill her demonic unborn child -- the fate of the world depends on it. ~ Tracie Cooper, Rovi

[Japanese birth, demon baby, unreleased video game](http://www.rottentomatoes.com/m/samourais/)

### Trailer

Comment: “peaking up from beneath the skin” — [_come on_, Rotten Tomatoes copy editors](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/peeking). Also my 38-year-old self desperately wants to see this.

Answer (score 1):

This is probably Cronenberg's [eXistenZ](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existenz). It starred Jude Law and Jennifer Jason Leigh. However, there are elements to this that don't seem to fit your description.

Comment: no ,its not eXistenZ